# display groups belonging to domain users

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have 2 users one on local machine and one on domain.: `user1` & `testdomain\user1`

Now both these users have different groups

```
user1 = group1, group3

testdomain\user1 = group2, group4
```

Now I wish to display these groups, I have no trouble displaying the groups of `user1` but I cannot display the groups of `testdomain\user1`.

My code is as below.

```
DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
DirectoryEntry user = AD.Children.Find(completeUserName, "user");
object obGroups = user.Invoke("Groups");

foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
{
    // Create object for each group.
    DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
    listOfMyWindowsGroups.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
}
```

where completeusername = user1 and testdomain\user1

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `WinNT://` provider is for backward compatibility only, and it only works for machine-local accounts. If you want to interrogate domain accounts, you **must** use the LDAP:// provider instead

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or later then have a look at [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx). These classes are far easy to work with. For example,

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "johndoe");
var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups()  // or user.GetUserGroups()
```

If its machine user then you have to use `ContextType.Machine`

Also have a look at these article that gives a bit of overview for the same:

http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S5

Comment: the getAuthorizationGroups doesn work and i get the error (5), and get groups gets me a value "Domain Users". please help me thanks..

Comment: This is permissions related issue - see if these threads give you any clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405646/error-with-userprincipal-getauthorizationgroups-method , http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/853148-system-directoryservices-getauthorizationgroups-function-error . Perhaps, you can ensure that current windows user has permissions to query AD authorization groups.