# How to determine all the groups a user belongs to (including nested groups) in ActiveDirectory and .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory, directoryservices

I have an application that uses ActiveDirecotry authorisation and it has been decided that it needs to support nested AD groups, e.g.:

```
MAIN_AD_GROUP
     |
     |-> SUB_GROUP
              | 
              |-> User
```

So, the user in not *directly* a member of `MAIN_AD_GROUP`. I'd like to be able to look for the user recursively, searching the groups nested in `MAIN_AD_GROUP`.

The main problem is that I'm using .NET 3.5 and there is a bug in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in .NET 3.5 whereby the method `UserPrincipal.IsMemberOf()` *will not work for groups with **more than 1500 users***. So I can't use `UserPrincipal.IsMemberOf()` and no, I can't switch to .NET 4 either.

I've worked around this last problem with the following function:

```
private bool IsMember(Principal userPrincipal, Principal groupPrincipal)
{
    using (var groups = userPrincipal.GetGroups())
    {
        var isMember = groups.Any(g => 
            g.DistinguishedName == groupPrincipal.DistinguishedName);
        return isMember;
    }
}
```

But `userPrincipal.GetGroups()` only returns the groups of which the user is a direct member.

How can I get this to work with nested groups?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Workaround #1

This bug is reported [here at Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522539/clr-forum-error-calling-principal-getauthorizationgroups-in-winxp-sp3) along with the following code that works around this issue by manually iterating through the `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` returned objects, catching this exception, and continuing on:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
var iterGroup = groups.GetEnumerator();
using (iterGroup)
{
    while (iterGroup.MoveNext())
    {
        try
        {
            Principal p = iterGroup.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
        catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException pex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

## Workaround #2

Another workaround [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/9dd81553-3539-4281-addd-3eb75e6e4d5d) avoids the `AccountManagement` class, and uses the `System.DirectoryServices` API instead:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.DirectoryServices;  

namespace GetGroupsForADUser  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            String username = "Gabriel";  

            List<string> userNestedMembership = new List<string>();  

            DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry(); // Use this to query the default domain
            //DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com", "username", "password"); // Use this to query a remote domain

            DirectorySearcher samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();  

            samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;  
            samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + username + ")";  
            samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");  

            SearchResult samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();  

            if (samResult != null)  
            {  
                DirectoryEntry theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();  
                theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });  

                foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])  
                {  
                    System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier mySID = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);  

                    DirectorySearcher sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();  

                    sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;  
                    sidSearcher.Filter = "(objectSid=" + mySID.Value + ")";  
                    sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");  

                    SearchResult sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();  

                    if (sidResult != null)  
                    {  
                        userNestedMembership.Add((string)sidResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]);  
                    }  
                }  

                foreach (string myEntry in userNestedMembership)  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(myEntry);  
                }  

            }  
            else 
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("The user doesn't exist");  
            }  

            Console.ReadKey();  

        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I chose to implement Workaround #2. YMMV with Workaround #1.

Comment: Good post. Workaround #1 fails on iterGroup.MoveNext() with the same error "There is no such object on the server".

Comment: Workaround 2 can work only if the program runs from a computer that is logged on to the domain.
It can't work if you are querying the ldap from a different domain.

Comment: @RonenFestinger Any Workaround #3 ?

Comment: @Kiquenet & @Ronen it looks like you can use another constructor for `DirectoryEntry domainConnection` to pass in a username and password that is valid on the different domain. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362724/cross-domain-authentication-using-directoryservices

Comment: I edited the answer to include a line of code that can be used for connecting to a remote domain: `DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com", "username", "password"); // Use this to query a remote domain`

Comment: How do you hug someone on this site!!!  Workaround number 2 is crazy efficient!!!  You just saved my entire day!

Answer (score 15):

Use `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()` instead - from its [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx):

> This method searches **all groups
>   recursively** and returns the groups in
>   which the user is a member. The
>   returned set may also include
>   additional groups that system would
>   consider the user a member of for
>   authorization purposes.
>
> The groups that are returned by this
>   method may include groups from a
>   different scope and store than the
>   principal. For example, if the
>   principal is an AD DS object that has
>   a DN of
>   "CN=SpecialGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com,
>   the returned set can contain groups
>   that belong to the
>   "CN=NormalGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this throws an `PrincipalOperationException` exception with the message "There is no such object on the server." The UserPrincipal definitely exists, as my method above *does* return the proper authorisations for top-level groups.

Comment: `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()` gets choked up if there are deleted groups that the user is still a member of

Comment: Just check if the group.Name is not null in that case @jproch

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but it's the top result on Google, so in case this helps anyone, here's what I came up with that uses the AccountManagement stuff, but makes this particular query much easier.

```
public static class AccountManagementExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNestedMemberOf(this Principal principal, GroupPrincipal group)
    {
        // LDAP Query for memberOf Nested 
        var filter = String.Format("(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={1}))",
                principal.SamAccountName,
                group.DistinguishedName
            );

        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(filter);

        var result = searcher.FindOne();

        return result != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way is to do a single AD query by having the right DirectorySearcher filter for e.g.

```
public bool CheckMemberShip(string userName)
    {

        bool membership = false;
        string connection = "LDAP://"+YOURDOMAIN;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(connection);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=GROUPNAME,OU=Groups,OU=ABC,OU=ABC,OU=IND,DC=ad,DC=COMPANY,DC=com)(|(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))";
        SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

        // No search result, hence no membership
        if (result == null)
        {
            membership = false;
        }

        entry.Close();
        entry.Dispose();
        mySearcher.Dispose();

        membership = true;
        return membership;
    }
```

You need to replace YOURDOMAIN and GROUPNAME with right values from your AD.

Source : [How to Recursively Get the Group Membership of a User in Active Directory using .NET/C# and LDAP (without just 2 hits to Active Directory)](http://ddkonline.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-recursively-get-group-membership.html)

Need to include `using System.DirectoryServices;`

Comment: This answer as is will always return true (given that there's a membership=true the line before the return)