# Cross Domain Authentication using DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-domain, directoryservices

I need to create a method for my intranet web application that will authenticate a user using `DirectoryServices`, either against a default domain, or a user specified one.

On my login form the user will be able to either give there credentials in the form of `"username"` and `"password`" or `"domain\username"` and `"password"`
The first case can be used when the user is in the same domain as the webserver and is quite straightfoward. The code I use is:

```
 string domain = "";
 // Code to check if the username is in form of "domain\user" or "user"
 string username = ParseUsername(username, out domain);
 if(domain == "")
    domain = defaultDomain;

 PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password); 
 bool IsAuthenticated = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password)
```

I pass the username and password to the PrincipalContext constructor in order to bind the call in cases where I try to access another domain.

For the local domain the code works fine. However when I try to check against another domain that is being specified through the username, then I get a "Server could not be contacted" error.

I also tried using different `ContextOptions` such as `ContextOptions.SimpleBind` or `ContextOptions.Negotiate`but I always seem to be getting the same result.

I need to implement this, since the application is being shipped to various customers, with either single domain or multiple domain environments. 
Is there something else I should specify in cases of "remote" domains? The code needs to be flexible since this will be deployed in various environments.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I must point out, that I prefer to do it using `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and `PrincipalContext` in order to take advantage of other functionality it provides as well.

Also, I must mention that for my tests, my Dev machine is on a 10.0.0.* network and the second domain I test against is on a 10.0.1.*. I have a route and all, and I can succesfuly connect using an ldap client, so the question is why I cannot connect to the domain via my asp.net application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with this solution to the problem.

In order to support multiple domains, either in trust relationships or even in isolated networks, first of all I added a NameValueCollection in my web.config to list the domains and their domain controllers.

```
  <domains>
    <add key="domain1" value="10.0.0.1"/>
    <add key="domain2" value="10.0.1.11"/>
  </domains>
```

(more info on the configuration addition in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338242/how-do-i-store-a-dictionary-object-in-my-web-config-file))

Then the next step was to read the domain from the User's credentials in the way I mention in the question. Having gotten the domain I try to lookup the according domain controller from the configuration values, in order to get the proper LDAP connection string. So my method is this:

```
private string GetLDAPConnection(string a_Domain, string a_Username, string a_Password)
{
    // Get the domain controller server for the specified domain
    NameValueCollection domains = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domains");
    string domainController = domains[a_Domain.ToLower()];

    string ldapConn = string.Format("LDAP://{0}/rootDSE", domainController);

    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(ldapConn, a_Username, a_Password);
    string serverName = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
    return string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", domainController, serverName);
}
```

Once I get back the proper connection string I make a new call in order to authenticate the user, by addressing the proper LDAP

```
    ...
    string ldapConn = GetLDAPConnection(domain, username, a_Password);                             
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapConn, username, a_Password);        

    try
    {
        try
        {
            object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        }
        catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException comExc)
        {
            LogException(comExc);
            return false;
        }

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = string.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", username);
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

From this point on I can also perform all the other queries I want such as the user's group membership etc.

Since the call to the remote domains needs to be bound to a user, I use the "calling" users credentials. This way the user get's authenticated and the Call is bound to the specific user. Furthermore, I specify a "default" domain, for cases where users provide their credentials without specifying the domain.

I did not manage to this however using the PrincipalContext as I wanted, but on the bright side, this solution is also applicable for older .NET 2.0 applications as well.

I am not sure that this is the best solution to the problem, however it seems to work in the tests we have so far performed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I got downvoted but here's what I think might be wrong, the trust level between the server/domain on which you code is hosted and the domain to which you are trying to contact might not be established. I can't provide you reasons why that might be happening.

```
[EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
```

You can try adding this above your function and see if it helps you to go through, but apart from that I don't see why would it be wrong to search on WinNT domain for all the possible users. Hope this helps

Comment: Security Restrictions are my first guess as well. However, in an older implementation of the method, I used to do it with DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher of older .NET 2.0 libraries. In that case, I needed to pass the username and password in order to bind the call and that would solve the double hop issue. Now, I just don't seem to connect at all.
The main difference now is that I need to allow the users to specify the domain which they belong to, so as to be more versatile.

Comment: I had a similar problem when the place I worked decided to migrate to a new domain. During the migration process we needed to keep both domains active. Therein I found that there were trust issues but could never figure out a solution to it. Instead I went with the WinNT approach where I would search for the userID over the entire network, get that object and then do manipulation as I needed. Also did a latency check for both methods to see if it WinNT was feasible and it turned out to be decent choice.

Comment: @NikosSteiakakis If you figure out the solution do write it here.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work for me, because I want this to work in cases where the domains might not even have a common global catalog.