# Checking for User Membership in Nested AD Groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices

I have an ASP.NET Framework 4.5 app with the following function to check if user is a member of an AD group:

```
public static bool IsUserGroupMember(string userName, string groupName)
{
    string domain = "ad.our.org";
    string defaultOU = "OU=Our_Department,DC=ad,DC=our,DC=org";
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, defaultOU, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
    GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);

    return oGroupPrincipal.Members.Contains(oUserPrincipal);
}
```

However, this only works when the user is directly a member of the group and not a member of another group nested within this group.

Hope to get help fixing this code to check membership recursively through every nested group within the group. I looked at answers to similar issues in StackOverflow but can't figure out how to best modify my function to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: For nested groups, i think this is the better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31725157/374133

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
public static bool IsUserGroupMember(string userName, string groupName)
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
    using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
    {
        return groups.OfType<GroupPrincipal>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(groupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Ashigore. But I am getting the error: DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal does not contain definition for 'OfType'?

Comment: @corix010 You need to include the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: @Antoops This most definitely gives the correct output. What this doesn't do is show distribution groups.

Comment: @Ashigore i got the output by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312744/how-to-determine-all-the-groups-a-user-belongs-to-including-nested-groups-in-a/31725157#31725157

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a **System.DirectoryServices.Protocols** library, u can use this specific filter for get ALL nested groups, where the user belongs to and is NOT a direct member only:

```
    var filterForNestedGroups = $"(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={user}))";
    var searchRequestForGroups = new SearchRequest(
        monitoredOptions.ActiveDirectoryDomainControllers, filterForNestedGroups, SearchScope.Subtree);

    var searchResponseForGroups = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequestForGroups);
    var groupList = new List<string>();
    var groups = searchResponseForGroups.Entries;
    var groupsCount = searchResponseForGroups.Entries.Count;

    for (var index = 0; index < groupsCount; index++)
    {
        var group = groups[index].Attributes["cn"]?[0].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(group) == false)
            groupList.Add(group);
    }
```

Please note that user variable MUST be a DistinguishedName value!